# Visual Studio Emulator for Android: Android Nougat

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

Is it possible to have Android N in Visual Studio Emulator for Android?

I do have Android 7 SDK Platform installed.

Comment: Not available at the moment.

Comment: @peterincumbria Thanks. I can see that. Any information when it's going to be available or any workarounds? Can I create the image by myself somehow? Beside just switching the emulator to another one.

Comment: I am in the same situation, I just hope the emulator is being further developed. An answer from one of the  developers would be good.

Comment: I wonder if there's a MSDN forum dedicated to the Visual Studio Emulator...

Comment: Please vote for the UserVoice item https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/16799356-support-android-api-level-24

Comment: I think VS Emulator is dead unfortunately. Too bad because I loved how the GPS simulator works.

Comment: what are the alternatives? for Android 7 and 8?